# Time dependent variation in CUDA kernel performance

Tags: performance, cuda

I've been benchmarking some CUDA programs (2D and 3D lattice boltzmann solvers) and have come across something unusual; I would expect some random variation in the performance of the solver over time, but over a variety of different problem sizes, block sizes, OS' and GPUs (not to mention that the 2D and 3D codes are completely separate and not different configurations of the same program) I can see a very clear sinusoidal fluctuation in kernel execution times. For the two GPUs I've tested on (K5000m and K20c) the variation seems to have a frequency in the 10-12Hz range.

Is there any known explanation for this? My go-to idea is thermal/power management but I've not been able to prove it. Has anyone else experienced this?

FURTHER INFO AND AN EXAMPLE

A MSVC2010 project for a small example code can be found at https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxtYXJram1hd3NvbnxneDplOWMwNWNhNDA4MmMwMjg The project requires CUDA 5.0 and a sm_30 device,although there is only one file so building the project manually would be trivial. The code is fairly self explanatory, 100 iterations of a simple kernel (kernels to read from several arrays and write to several arrays are performed by default) are timed and their results printed to a file.  Performing a FFT of the execution times yields visible peak near 11Hz on a K5000m. I would post an image  but I don't have the reputation.

Comment: What is the amplitude of the variation in execution time?

Comment: In the order of 10s of microseconds, I had initially thought it was the rounding error of timing using cudaEvents, but they *should* have a resolution of around 0.5 microseconds.

Comment: Was the fluid moving in a sinusoidal accelerated pattern? There are If-sentences in kernels like these and the performance changes as condition goes bad(complete random branching accross threads) and good(there is an order in threads about branching)

Comment: No, the test case is a lid driven cavity. The amount of branching due to boundaries is constant for a given domain size. I wrote the code myself so I'm confident it's not an application level issue.

Comment: @talonmies did you get a chance to look into this? I asked on the Nvidia dev forums and noone could find an answer.

Comment: For "Has anyone else experienced this?" perhaps you've provided enough info.  However,  to "look into this", you probably should provide a complete code, along with your detailed timing observations. SO expects that "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance. "  Is 10s of microseconds a big deal in your setup?  For a large kernel, that should be in the noise, as the normal kernel launch overhead is on the order of a few microseconds, minimum.

Comment: I've added a link to a sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Windows has behavioral effects on the detailed timing of GPU kernel execution, especially when running the GPU in WDDM mode.  Please re-run your observation and FFT preferably in a linux environment where X is not also running on the GPU.  This will give you the most consistent behavior.  The CUDA driver in a WDDM setup is subject, to some degree, to the windows operating system.

I ran your code on an SM35 device, CentOS 5.5, CUDA 5.5, and got the following Times.dat output:

> 0.007648 0.0024 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.00192 0.001888 0.001888 0.00192 0.00192 0.001856 0.00192 0.001888 0.00192 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.00192 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001856 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.002016 0.001888 0.001888 0.00192 0.001952 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.00192 0.00192 0.001888 0.00192 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.00192 0.001888 0.001888 0.001856 0.001888 0.00192 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.003904 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.00192 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.00192 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.00192 0.001888 0.00192 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888
>   0.001888 0.00192 0.001888 0.00192 0.001856 0.001888 0.001856 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001952 0.001888 0.001888 0.00192 0.00192 0.00192 0.001888 0.001888 0.001952 0.001888 0.00192 0.001888 0.001856 0.001888 0.00192 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.00192 0.001856 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.00192 0.00192 0.001888 0.001888 0.00192 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.00192 0.001888 0.00192 0.001888 0.001888 0.00192 0.001888 0.00192 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.00192 0.004448 0.001888 0.001952 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001856 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.00192 0.001856 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001856 0.001888 0.001888 0.001856 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888 0.001888

There is occasional variation however don't forget your `cudaTime` variable is capturing a time in *milliseconds*.  So the variation I see in the above data is mostly on the order of less than 1 microsecond variation, run to run.

Throwing out the first number, the largest variation I see is about 2-3 microseconds in a few cases.  Given that the execution time measured is less than 2 microseconds typically, this is a large variation but it's still in the noise, and not anything like the 10's of microseconds you're reporting.

To my untrained eye I also don't see any sinusoidal pattern in the data, but if you tell me there's an 11Hz frequency in there (not even sure what that means, since these data points are not time-stamped that I can see) -- I'll take your word for it.

Comment: The time stamping is taken by summing the execution times of the previous iterations; it's obviously not exact as it ignores the time taken up by timing the kernel, but it was the consistency of the results that concerned me rather than the exact frequency. Your results don't seem to exhibit this behaviour, I was under the impression that the K20c I've been using made no use of x. Perhaps I'm wrong, I'll run my sample on that machine and confirm.

Comment: As for the order of the variation, I don't believe that the sample will produce that as it's very stripped down, intended to reproduce the sinusoidal behaviour rather than the magnitude.